# serialize underscored property ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

My serialzer works fine, exept for underscored properties. The sctucture of the JSON from server is:

```
var services = {
    services:[{
      id:8,
      name:"Codin'",
      service_category:{
        id:5,
        iso_code:"BDT",
        prop:"Ohmmmm"
      }
    },
      {
      id:7,
      name:"PR",
      service_category:{
        id:2,
        iso_code:"SFD",
        prop:"Naraya"
      }
    }] 
  };
```

after serialisation the payload looks like this:

```
var services = {
    services:[{
      id:8,
      name:"Codin'",
      service_category:5
    },
      {
      id:7,
      name:"PR",
      service_category:2
    }],
    serviceCategories:[{
        id:5,
        iso_code:"BDT",
        prop:"Ohmmmm"
      },
     {
        id:2,
        iso_code:"SFD",
        prop:"Naraya"
      }
    ]
  };
```

But it in the template i cant access serviceCategory's prop

The models

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    serviceCategory: DS.belongsTo('serviceCategory')
});

App.ServiceCategory = DS.Model.extend({
    iso_code: DS.attr('string'),
    prop:DS.attr()
});
```

Here is the JsBin as usual: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has `service_category` as the property name in the service.

Easy fix is:

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    service_category: DS.belongsTo('serviceCategory')
});
```

and

```
 <td>{{item.service_category.prop}} </td>
```

http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/570/edit